# Filtering MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, mapkit, core-location

I have a MKMapView Which Shows Some Annotations from a JSON File and shows User current Location i want to have a filter in the mapView which the user can choose how far from his current location does he want the MKAnnotations to be shown till example 5 miles..

Basically like map filtering on foursquare where you can filter how far from your location you want the restaurants to be shown

This is my Main current code related to the questions..

```
@interface ViewController () <MKMapViewDelegate , CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize mapView;

/*
 Establish MapView delegate
 Add the Gesture Recogniser to the Map
 */
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.mapView setDelegate:self];
    //[self addGestureRecogniserToMapView];

    mapView.showsUserLocation= YES;
    mapView.showsTraffic = YES;
    mapView.showsBuildings = YES;

  __block NSArray *annoations;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    annoations = [self parseJSONCities];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

        [self.mapView addAnnotations:annoations];
        [self.mapView showAnnotations:annoations animated:YES];

    });
});

    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        NSLog(@"Location :)");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"-)_");
    }


   }


- (NSMutableArray *)parseJSONCities{

    NSMutableArray *retval = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *jsonPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"capitals"
                                                         ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                    options:kNilOptions
                                                      error:&error];

    for (JFMapAnnotation *record in json) {

        JFMapAnnotation *temp = [[JFMapAnnotation alloc]init];
        [temp setTitle:[record valueForKey:@"Capital"]];
        [temp setSubtitle:[record valueForKey:@"Country"]];
        [temp setCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[record valueForKey:@"Latitude"]floatValue], [[record valueForKey:@"Longitude"]floatValue])];
        [retval addObject:temp];

    }

    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the coordinates of the record, create a `CLLocation` object with the initializer

```
init(latitude latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude longitude: CLLocationDegrees)
```

From there, use the instance method

```
distanceFromLocation(_:CLLocation)
```

with the user location to get the distance **(in meters)** the annotation is from the user. After that, a simple conversion from meters to miles **(divide by 1609.34)** should shape you up real nicely to filter which annotations are visible. Good luck!

Comment: @Aryan, I would be interested to know how this solution worked out for you. Do you need any further help? Please respond.